# How to use compound locators when testing with Jasmine and Protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, automation, jasmine, protractor

Can someone provide me an example of how I can use multiple locators when testing using Jasmine and Protractor?

Lets say I have 3 list elements in the form of LINKS and all of these LIST ELEMENTS have the same attributes; However, each of these are links with unique name to navigate to a new "Angular State"...

example all three links have in them the following:

`<li> ng-repeat="bb" ng-class="{'active': dropdown.isActive}" class="ng-scope active"</li>`

and then each of the links have their own names, for example:

```
<a ui-sref="search" class="ng-binding" href="#/Search"> Search </a>
<a ui-sref="home" class="ng-binding" href="#/Search"> Home </a> 
<a ui-sref="todo" class="ng-binding" href="#/Search"> ToDo </a>
```

The only thing that is unique between the 3 page objects is:
`ui-sref="search"`, `ui-sref="home"`, `ui-sref="todo"...`

How can I use one common locator from the list elements and a unique locator from link element to ensure that I am interacting with the correct link every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using a [custom locator](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#protractorbyprototypeaddlocator) to deal with `ui-sref` :

```
// Usage:
var searchLinkElm = element(by.uisref('search'));
var homeLinkElm = element(by.uisref('home'));
var todoLinkElm = element(by.uisref('todo'));

// Interaction
it('works', function() {
    expect(searchLinkElm.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
    searchLinkElm.click();
});

// within your onPrepare block
by.addLocator('uisref', function(toState, opt_parentElement) {
    var using = opt_parentElement || document;

    var prefixes = ['ui-sref'];
    for (var p = 0; p < prefixes.length; ++p) {
        var selector = '*[' + prefixes[p] + '="' + toState + '"]';
        var inputs = using.querySelectorAll(selector);
        if (inputs.length) {
            return inputs;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is pretty advance for me but I will take some time to understand it and let you know if it works. Can you summarize for me your logic? Just give me a direction on what your code does so that I have a way to follow. Thanks again.

Comment: I just click the ui-sref link then start interacting with the new page state, checking for elements present with isPresent() and/or isDisplayed() and so on... nothing too fancy i think.

Comment: You should pay attention to put the `by.addLocator(..` code [within an onPrepare section like here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/a368de0b74db35a90d/spec/withLoginConf.js#L16).

Comment: Elgalu, I wasn't able to really use this entirely, but it did give me a simpler solution and something to work towards.. Thanks for the help.